# Sinch in-call Status Bae text Modifying

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch

We are currently developing a live app using Sinch Voice services to intiate call between two peers . When the app is in the background, the in-call status bar displays the following message:
App Name (Recording)

Since we are not recording any of the sessions, we would like to omit the use of the word "Recording" from the in-call status bar. Any idea how to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are actually recording according to Apple, the microphone is active and is recording your voice and sending it to the other side. Unfortunately there is nothing to be done about this, its built in to the iOS to display that status bar when the microphone is active.